# SQL Server condition not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Below is part of a SQL Server query which is not working as expected. I don't know why, but condition falls through this part, like nothing is inserted (like all three conditions are set to NULL). What am I doing wrong here?

Input parameters for the stored procedure:

```
    @cStockPacked varchar(1) = NULL,
    @cWrittenDown varchar(1) = NULL,
    @cInPreparation varchar(1) = NULL
```

Part of the query which is not working:

```
(   
    (@cStockPacked IS NULL OR 
     (@cStockPacked = '1' AND MEST.MEST_STA = '1')
    )
    OR
    (@cInPreparation IS NULL OR 
     (@cInPreparation = '1' AND MEST.MEST_STA = '2')
    )
    OR
    (@cWrittenDown IS NULL OR 
     (@cWrittenDown = '1' AND MEST.MEST_STA = '4')
    )   
)
```

I've tried to hard code conditions, everything worked as expected:

```
(
    MEST.MEST_STA = '1' OR MEST.MEST_STA = '2' OR MEST.MEST_STA = '4'
)
```

I've tried with one condition (hardcoded), then with two and later with all three. All was good. I want to achieve the same result with query pasted above, but something is obviously wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Whole procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CAMERC_HLP]
    (   , @cStockPacked varchar(1) = NULL
        , @cWrittenDown varchar(1) = NULL
        , @cInPreparation varchar(1) = NULL
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        MEST.MEST_QUA, MERC_STA, MERC_NME,
        MERC_DES, MERC_NTO, MERC_UNI, MERC_LPR, 
        MERC.UNIT_KEY,
        COUNT_ALL_ROWS = COUNT(*) OVER()
    FROM 
        CAMERC MERC 
    INNER JOIN  
        CAMEGR CAMEGR ON MERC.MEGR_KEY = CAMEGR.MEGR_KEY
    INNER JOIN 
        CAMEST MEST ON MERC.MERC_KEY = MEST.MERC_KEY
    WHERE                                   
        (@cMERC_NME IS NULL OR MERC_NME LIKE '%' + @cMERC_NME + '%')
        AND
        (@iMEGR_KEY IS NULL OR MERC.MEGR_KEY IN (SELECT MEGR_KEY FROM CTE))         
        AND
        (@cMERC_CDO1 IS NULL OR MERC_CDO1 LIKE '%' + @cMERC_CDO1 + '%') 
        AND     
        and
        (   
            (@cStockPacked IS NULL OR @cStockPacked = '1' AND MEST.MEST_STA = '1')
            OR
            (@cInPreparation IS NULL OR (@cInPreparation = '1' AND MEST.MEST_STA = '2'))
            OR
            (@cWrittenDown IS NULL OR (@cWrittenDown = '1' AND MEST.MEST_STA = '4'))                
        )
END
```

Comment: Think you are going to have to show more of the query than that, people will need the context to understand what the problem could be. For example how is @cStockPacked defined

Comment: I don't really understand the question.  The code that "doesn't work" is implementing different logic from the code that "does work".  I'm am not surprised that different logic produces different results.

Comment: Why is different logic? I've just hardcoded what I would like to come out from condition.

Comment: There really isn't enough of a code sample to have any idea. First question : are you certain you know about all the weird ways NULLs work. Secondly I suggest you use SQL Profiler to profile your stored procedure and then hopefully everything will be shown in black and white.

Comment: **Side notes:** you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Site note #2: and also: `varchar(1)` really doesn't make a whole lot of sense - since it's only really **1** character, why incur the 2-byte overhead for the `varchar` part?? Just use `char(1)` instead - just as good, no overhead

Comment: @marc_s thanks, you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may looking for this

```
(
  (   
    (@cStockPacked IS NOT NULL AND @cStockPacked = '1' AND MEST.MEST_STA = '1') OR
    (@cInPreparation IS NOT NULL AND @cInPreparation = '1' AND MEST.MEST_STA = '2') OR
    (@cWrittenDown IS NOT NULL AND @cWrittenDown = '1' AND MEST.MEST_STA = '4')    
  )
  OR
  ( @cStockPacked IS NULL OR @cInPreparation IS NULL OR @cWrittenDown IS NULL )
)
```

Comment: That's it :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is a problem - if I don't set any of those conditions, nothing shows up. I don't get any results.

Comment: Updated Ans. Make sure you have to use exact parenthesis as used in Ans

Comment: The `IS NOT NULL` conditions are completely superfluous of course.

Comment: @FrenkyB: You forgot to tell us in your request that you want to see all records in case all criteria is set to null (as opposed to: don't show StockPacked + don't show InPreparation + don't show WrittenDown).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you accepted that answer as correct, it does not make much sense to test var for NULL with those conditions.

All you need - to make these conditions same as others. Just like this:

```
AND (@cMERC_NME IS NULL OR MERC_NME LIKE '%' + @cMERC_NME + '%')
```

update them to:

```
    AND (@cStockPacked IS NULL OR (@cStockPacked = '1' AND MEST.MEST_STA = '1'))
    AND (@cInPreparation IS NULL OR (@cInPreparation = '1' AND MEST.MEST_STA = '2'))
    AND (@cWrittenDown IS NULL OR (@cWrittenDown = '1' AND MEST.MEST_STA = '4'))
```

that's it.